# Why was the right-handed (fake) Infinity Gauntlet so large?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

From memory, the fake (right-handed) Infinity Gauntlet existed before Thanos made Etri create the left-handed version that he used with the real Infinity Stones.

[image: Hela next to big fake gauntlet]

This gauntlet is obviously sized for Titans, but who was it made for, and why?

Comment: There's no indication it was made for anything other than sitting in the vault/trophy room is there? After all it is fake.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - That sounds like an answer; why don't you turn it into one? :)

Comment: Thanos isn't the only large being in the universe. Further, there's no indication that the fake was meant to be Odin's gauntlet. It's in the trophy room - he probably defeated some monster who had it OR he had it created and felt that it had to be 'larger than life'.

Comment: Obviously the real answer is out of universe, they didn't know it was going to be a fake in the earlier Thor film, they only decided to add the crafting bit with Eitrig later.

Answer (score 1):

This Gauntlet was nothing more then a fake. In Ragnarok, we see a model/sculpture of the gauntlet in at the Etri's smith. The gauntlet most likely needed a certain size to properly have the right specifications to withstand the power of the infinity stones. Which explains the size. The gauntlet was simply there as a trophy for Odin and to make everyone believe the gauntlet was in safe hands to prevent fear amongst the asgaurdians.